# Excel VBA AutoFilter Criteria From List Box with Multiple Selections

Tags: excel, vba

I want to take a List Box with one or Multiple Selections then put the selected values into the auto filter criteria under one column. So for instance if I choose 15 and 30 it would be like this picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XNHb.png)

But I cant seem to get it too work. The code works if I manually put a value there or type an array like this for multiple values.

```
Array("15", "30")
```

Im not sure if my array implementation is wrong as Im new to VBA and not familiar with arrays.
Or there is a different way to achieve what I want.

Current Code Below

```
Private Sub Test_Click()
Dim FoundCodeString As Range
Dim x() As Variant
ReDim x(0)


 For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
     x(UBound(x)) = Me.ListBox1.List(i)
     ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) + 1)
    End If
 Next i

For k = 1 To fdFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=fdFileDialog.SelectedItems(k)
    Set FoundCodeString = Sheets(1).Rows("1").Find(What:="Code", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)        'Search For "Code" String in Row 1
    ActiveSheet.Rows("1").AutoFilter Field:=FoundCodeString.Column, Criteria1:=x, Operator:=xlFilterValues
 Next k
 
End Sub
```

Comment: could you run a check of two things just quickly on this.  put `stop` between `next i` and `for` then open the locals window (View-> locals window) run the code until it stops at this point and take a look at the array x: 1 does it have the values you expect in it. 2. are those values in the same format as the column i.e. number, text (text will show in quotes i.e "2").

Comment: It shows the the correct items selected as Variant Doubles but also 1  Variant empty  some reason. As far as my research went the "Operator:=xlFilterValues" is suppose to filter through an array if given one. Not Sure if the Variant Empty is messing it up.

Comment: The Format is Not the same as "#", "#"  but possible it needs to be, ive found other examples online and they simple just feed the criteria an Array but I cant seem to get it to work

Comment: Try `transpose` or `cstr` on `x`.

Comment: @findwindow Could you elaborate? On what this accomplishes

Comment: Turns it into a string.

Comment: i think @findwindow is suggesting that for this [link](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2010/12/15/excel-autofilter-with-criteria-in-a-range/#:~:text=In%20an%20Excel%20VBA%20procedure,the%20values%20as%20an%20array.&text=Then%2C%20to%20use%20this%20variable,row%2C%20instead%20of%20a%20column.) if you scroll down most of the way it tells about the transpose of the array, otherwise the first entry is used.  BTW the last empty cell is introduced when your if statement is last executed `x(UBound(x)) = Me.ListBox1.List(i)` runs and then `ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) + 1)` adds entry to the array

Comment: @findwindow You were right! Simple Changing it too a string solved the issue! Thanks So Much!